# Read a version number from a file in configure.ac

Tags: autoconf

I define my project version number in a plain text file instead of configure.ac for some reasons. I would like to create a statement that would read the version number and store it during compilation time.

Right now my configure.ac looks like this:

```
AC_INIT([my program],[999.9.9])
```

I would like to have something like:

```
AC_INIT([my program],[ $(cat VERSION) ])
```

This wont work of course. What is the trick here? (I know I am loosing some portability - I don't care at the moment). Thanks!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Try:

```
AC_INIT([my program], m4_esyscmd([tr -d '\n' < VERSION]))
```

Edited with fixes suggested in the comments.

I was also able to remove the non-portable `tr` invocation using:

```
AC_INIT([my program], [m4_translit(m4_esyscmd([cat VERSION]),m4_newline)])
```

which seems to work just as well, as does the solution suggested by Enrico in the comments below:

```
AC_INIT([my program], [m4_esyscmd_s([cat VERSION])])
```

Comment: Got configure.ac:5: warning: AC_INIT: not a literal:  m4_esyscmd([echo 9.9| tr -d '\n']) but *it works*! Thanks.

Comment: @lzap: You can remove the quotes around `m4_esyscmd(...)` so that it is evaluated before calling `AC_INIT`.  This way `AC_INIT` gets a literal.  I would also remove the invocation of `cat`, for efficiency:  `AC_INIT([my program], m4_esyscmd([tr -d '\n' <VERSION]))`

Comment: You may use `m4_esyscmd_s` instead of `m4_esyscmd` to have trailing newlines removed without using `tr`.

Comment: This is the approach that autoconf itself uses to dynamically generate its own version number.  See [this mailing list post](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/autoconf/2007-12/msg00027.html) and [the source code](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=autoconf.git;a=blob;f=configure.ac;h=2709a0d1370a62092ba29ec14b55efc22560fa55;hb=HEAD#l21).

Comment: This solution still generates the warning for me. I'm pulling a hash value and see: `configure.ac:3: warning: AC_INIT: not a literal: a0aabf81`

Answer (score 7):

You can simply use the native macro `m4_include()` (instead of invoking `tr` or `cat` via `m4_esyscmd_s()` as suggested by **ldav1s**),

```
AC_INIT([foo], m4_normalize(m4_include([VERSION])))
```

which is also what the official guide of **GNU M4** [suggests](https://www.gnu.org/software/m4/manual/m4.html#Include) fo similar cases:

> ```
> $ cat examples/incl.m4
> ⇒Include file start
> ⇒foo
> ⇒Include file end
> ```
>
> […]
>
> The fact that `include` and `sinclude` expand to the contents of the
>   file can be used to define macros that operate on entire files. Here
>   is an example, which defines ‘`bar`’ to expand to the contents of
>   `incl.m4`:
>
> ```
> $ m4 -I examples
> define(`bar', include(`incl.m4'))
> ⇒
> This is `bar':  >>bar<<
> ⇒This is bar:  >>Include file start
> ⇒foo
> ⇒Include file end
> ⇒<<
> ```

Advantages:

- By using `m4_normalize(m4_include([VERSION]))` instead of `m4_esyscmd_s([cat VERSION])` the `VERSION` file is added to the `DIST_COMMON` variable in the `Makefile` – which means that **the `VERSION` file is automatically redistributed when the user launches `make dist`**
- By using `m4_normalize(m4_include([VERSION]))` instead of `m4_esyscmd_s([cat VERSION])` the `VERSION` file is added to the prerequisites of `make aclocal.m4` (which means that each time you modify the `VERSION` file the `configure` script gets automatically updated)

**GNU M4** offers also [support for regular expressions](https://www.gnu.org/software/m4/manual/m4.html#Regexp), so if you want to make sure that the version string always follows a particular pattern – or if the `VERSION` file contains more text than just the version string – you can use `m4_bregexp()` to find what you are looking for:

```
AC_INIT([foo], m4_bregexp(m4_quote(m4_include([VERSION])), [[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+], [\&]))
```

This is also the safest approach, since if the regular expression above cannot be found in the `VERSION` file the second argument of `AC_INIT()` simply expands to an empty string and the following error message is thrown by **Autoconf**:

```
error: AC_INIT should be called with package and version arguments
```

A typical case where it can be useful to invoke `m4_bregexp()` to process the content of a `VERSION` file is when this contains a three-number version string (`MAJOR.MINOR.REVISION`) but you only want a two-number version string (`MAJOR.MINOR`) as the expansion of your `AC_PACKAGE_VERSION` macro.

If you are familiar with regular expressions and capturing parentheses and you want to be able to do more complex tasks, I had written this general purpose variadic macro (you can paste it at the beginning of your `configure.ac`),

```
dnl  n4_define_substrings_as(string, regexp, macro0[, macro1[, ... macroN ]])
dnl  ***************************************************************************
dnl
dnl  Searches for the first match of `regexp` in `string` and defines custom
dnl  macros accordingly
dnl
dnl  For both the entire regular expression `regexp` (`\0`) and each
dnl  sub-expression within capturing parentheses (`\1`, `\2`, `\3`, ... , `\N`)
dnl  a macro expanding to the corresponding matching text will be created,
dnl  named according to the argument `macroN` passed. If a `macroN` argument is
dnl  omitted or empty, the corresponding parentheses in the regular expression
dnl  will be considered as non-capturing. If `regexp` cannot be found in
dnl  `string` no macro will be defined. If `regexp` can be found but some of
dnl  its capturing parentheses cannot, the macro(s) corresponding to the latter
dnl  will be defined as empty strings.
dnl
dnl  Source: https://github.com/madmurphy/not-autotools
dnl
dnl  ***************************************************************************
m4_define([n4_define_substrings_as],
    [m4_bregexp([$1], [$2],
        m4_ifnblank([$3],
            [[m4_define(m4_normalize([$3]), [m4_quote(\&)])]])[]m4_if(m4_eval([$# > 3]), [1],
            [m4_for([_idx_], [4], [$#], [1],
                [m4_ifnblank(m4_quote(m4_argn(_idx_, $@)),
                    [[m4_define(m4_normalize(m4_argn(]_idx_[, $@)), m4_quote(\]m4_eval(_idx_[ - 3])[))]])])]))])
```

which can be used for doing:

```
n4_define_substrings_as(

    m4_include([VERSION]),

    [\([0-9]+\)\s*\.\s*\([0-9]+\)\s*\.\s*\([0-9]+\)],

    [FOO_VERSION_STRING], [FOO_VERSION_MAJOR], [FOO_VERSION_MINOR], [FOO_VERSION_REVISION]

)

AC_INIT([foo], FOO_VERSION_MAJOR[.]FOO_VERSION_MINOR[.]FOO_VERSION_REVISION)
```

so that the macros `FOO_VERSION_MAJOR`, `FOO_VERSION_MINOR` and `FOO_VERSION_REVISION` are always available within `configure.ac`.

> **Note:** The `n4_` prefix in the `n4_define_substrings_as()` macro name stands for “**N**ot m**4**sugar”.

If the regular expression above cannot be found in the `VERSION` file, `n4_define_substrings_as()` safely does not define the corresponding macro names. This allows to generate an error for this particular case (the following line must be pasted immediately after `AC_INIT()`):

```
m4_ifndef([FOO_VERSION_STRING], [AC_MSG_ERROR([invalid version format in `VERSION` file])])
```

For as trivial as it can look to read a simple `VERSION` file, things get trickier if you want to retrive the version string from a `package.json` file. Here the `n4_define_substrings_as()` macro can come very much in handy:

```
n4_define_substrings_as(

    m4_quote(m4_include([package.json])),

    ["?version"?:\s*"?\s*\(\([0-9]+\)\s*\.\s*\([0-9]+\)\s*\.\s*\([0-9]+\)\)\s*"?],

    [JSON_ENTRY], [FOO_VERSION_STRING], [FOO_VERSION_MAJOR], [FOO_VERSION_MINOR], [FOO_VERSION_REVISION]

)

AC_INIT([foo], FOO_VERSION_MAJOR[.]FOO_VERSION_MINOR[.]FOO_VERSION_REVISION)
```

The `n4_define_substrings_as()` macro accepts also empty arguments, so if you prefer you may replace the `[JSON_ENTRY]` argument with `[]`, since probably you are never going to use the JSON source string `"version": "999.9.9"`.

If you only need to retrieve the full version string from a `package.json` file but you don't need to use `FOO_VERSION_MAJOR`, `FOO_VERSION_MINOR` and `FOO_VERSION_REVISION`, you can get rid of some of the capturing parentheses in the regular expression above, as in the following example:

```
n4_define_substrings_as(

    m4_quote(m4_include([package.json])),

    ["?version"?:\s*"?\s*\([0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\)\s*"?],

    [], [FOO_VERSION_STRING]

)

AC_INIT([foo], FOO_VERSION_STRING)
```

For completeness, since the last example has only one string to capture, it can also be rewritten without using `n4_define_substrings_as()` as:

```
AC_INIT([foo],
    m4_bregexp(m4_quote(m4_include([package.json])),
        ["?version"?:\s*"?\s*\([0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\)\s*"?],
        [\1]))
```