# Create a version number for AC_INIT

Tags: git, autotools, autoconf

I read this post: [Read a version number from a file in configure.ac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8559456/read-a-version-number-from-a-file-in-configure-ac) and it didn't help me...

I have this line in my configure.ac:

```
AC_INIT([some library],
    m4_esyscmd(echo $(git describe)$(git status --porcelain | awk '{if ($1 == "M") {print "-dirty";exit}}')),
    [email@address.xx],
    [],
    [www.website.com])
```

Wiht the "echo..." expression I want to get the string provided by `git describe` and append a `-dirty` if modified files exist.

I get the warning:

```
configure.ac:8: warning: AC_INIT: not a literal: ver0.1-6-g3153e9f
```

I tried with and without square brackets and quotes. I am out of ideas...

Answer (score 0):

I just solved it by using `m4_esyscmd_s` instead of `m4_esyscmd`.