# Using a variable in AC_INIT

Tags: autotools

Is there any way to pass in a variable to AC_INIT?
eg

```
VERSION = 0.1
AC_INIT([my_package],$VERSION)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Read a version number from a file in configure.ac](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8559456/read-a-version-number-from-a-file-in-configure-ac)

Answer (score 12):

From the manual:

> The arguments of 'AC_INIT' must be static, i.e., there should **not
>     be any shell computation, quotes, or newlines, but they can be
>     computed by M4**.  This is because the package information strings
>     are expanded at M4 time into several contexts, and must give the
>     same text at shell time whether used in single-quoted strings,
>     double-quoted strings, quoted here-documents, or unquoted
>     here-documents.  **It is permissible to use 'm4_esyscmd' or
>     'm4_esyscmd_s' for computing a version string** that changes with
>     every commit to a version control system (in fact, Autoconf does
>     just that, for all builds of the development tree made between
>     releases).

This is what autoconf (currently) uses:

```
AC_INIT([GNU Autoconf],
    m4_esyscmd([build-aux/git-version-gen .tarball-version]),
    [bug-autoconf@gnu.org])
```

If you don't need to read the version from an outside source, here's what GLIB uses:

```
m4_define([glib_major_version], [2])
m4_define([glib_minor_version], [41])
m4_define([glib_micro_version], [0])
...
m4_define([glib_version],
      [glib_major_version.glib_minor_version.glib_micro_version])

...
AC_INIT(glib, [glib_version], ...)
```

Of course, you will have to use M4 constructs instead of shell, like `m4_if()`, `m4_eval()`, etc.

Comment: For anyone getting "error: AC_INIT should be called with package and version arguments", I was able to make it work by enclosing the m4_esyscmd in square brackets.
Also, if you happen to be getting your version number using a script that does "echo" at the end, be sure to use "-ne". My configure script was not happy with a newline in the version string!