# Prevent "#define PACKAGE_VERSION" from appearing in config.h

Tags: autotools, autoconf, m4

The package version (see `AC_INIT`) of my medium-sized autotools project changes quite often. When the package version changes, I suffer from unnecessary rebuild of the whole project, because `PACKAGE_VERSION` and friends in `config.h` has changed and `config.h` is included in all source files.

The version is actually needed in just one source file and I'd like to put these definitions in a separate generated header and include it in this source file.

In file `general.m4` belonging to autoconf I see the following:

```
m4_define([_AC_INIT_PREPARE],
...
AC_DEFINE_UNQUOTED([PACKAGE_VERSION], ["$PACKAGE_VERSION"],
           [Define to the version of this package.])dnl
AC_DEFINE_UNQUOTED([PACKAGE_STRING], ["$PACKAGE_STRING"],
           [Define to the full name and version of this package.])dnl
```

In file `init.m4` belonging to automake:

```
AC_DEFUN([AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE],
...
 AC_DEFINE_UNQUOTED([VERSION], ["$VERSION"], [Version number of package])])dnl
```

I'd like to undo the effects of all three.
Currently, my `configure.ac` has these lines:

```
AC_INIT(pkgname, [1.2.3])
AC_CONFIG_HEADERS(config.h)
AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE([1.11 parallel-tests -Wno-portability tar-ustar])
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Read a version number from a file in configure.ac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8559456/read-a-version-number-from-a-file-in-configure-ac)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can prevent *some* of those symbols from being defined by specifying `no-define` among the Automake options in `AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE`, but that does not fully solve your problem because `PACKAGE_VERSION` itself will not be affected.  [It is defined by `AC_INIT`](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.69/html_node/Initializing-configure.html#Initializing-configure), and to the best of my knowledge, Autoconf does not provide a mechanism to suppress that.

Supposing, then, that you don't want to adjust your versioning practices (it's very strange that your version number changes so frequently that this is an issue), and that you reject the notion that it's a reasonable policy to perform a clean build whenever a version number change occurs, my best recommendation is to patch the `configure` script after (re)generating it.  You'll need to sort out what changes need to be made, but once you do, I expect you'll be able to write a tiny `sed`- or `awk`-based script to do it whenever needed.